# Why does Node.js have an 1.76 Gb memory limit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, v8

... is there only a very technical reason behind this, maybe simply because the V8 wasn't developed with server side Javascript in mind?
Or is there a reason more related to the architecture and nature of Node.js? Is there a reason why I should consider to use Node.js for streaming and piping rather than for loading and processing bigger amounts of data, besides "because then you have to increase the memory limit"?

Comment: If the memory limit is to low, gc would trigger to often, if the memory is to large gc would stop the world to long. But for shure you can increase the memory limit easily. This is only a default

Answer (score 5):

The primary reason why there is a limit at all is to protect the rest of the system from out-of-control memory consumers (i.e. when you have several processes running, and one of them consumes all the memory it can get, you want that one to run into its own limit rather than affecting everything else in the system). This is particularly true for the browser scenario (you don't want one tab to consume all your memory at the expense of all other tabs), but applies in many server-side scenarios as well.

The default value of the limit is more or less arbitrary; it seems to be a reasonable compromise for most purposes. If you need more, feel free to raise it. 64-bit builds of modern V8 versions ("modern" = from the last few years) support extremely large heaps if your app needs them.

Regarding your last question, "streaming and piping" are generally useful techniques for working with large amounts of data, regardless of whether you're using Node.js or any other technology. Code that reads all of its input data in one go tends to be easier to write, but is always prone to running into limits: 
for example, physical memory size of the machine it's running on. You can "fix" that one by buying more memory, but if your code uses streaming and reasonably sized buffers, it'll be able to process much bigger input data with much lower hardware requirements, and it might even run faster.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations! What do you think about "If the memory limit is to low, gc would trigger to often, if the memory is to large gc would stop the world to long" (see comment above), is Node.js's GC really blocking the event loop? That would be a good reason as well...

Comment: V8 hasn't had a "stop-the-world" GC since late 2011. The GC does its work partially on the main thread (in small incremental steps so it doesn't block long), and partially in the background. The total cost of GC work is proportional to how much you allocate; in other words: of course an application that uses little memory also spends less time doing GC. But this is really unrelated to the max heap size.

Comment: Could you give a source for that? Im curious to update my knowledge ;)

Comment: Source for what? Original "new GC" announcement: https://blog.chromium.org/2011/11/game-changer-for-interactive.html . More recent insight into ongoing improvements: https://v8project.blogspot.com/2015/08/getting-garbage-collection-for-free.html . And of course the ultimate source of truth is the source: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/master/src/heap/

Comment: Your second source claims "In order to avoid pausing the main thread for such long periods, V8 has long had the ability to incrementally mark live objects in many small steps, with the aim to keep each marking steps below 5 ms in duration.", which means it's not that bad, but still they are stopping the whole world while collecting garbage, isn't? Does this concept scale for applications claiming more memory?

Comment: "Collecting garbage" is not just one action. As I wrote before, some phases happen on the foreground thread, some happen in the background. The team is working on moving more and more into the background. And yes, the concept scales. (Of course using more memory gives the garbage collector more work to do, but that's called "scaling".)